# Sufficient conditions for continuous differentiability of $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}g_n(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

I have this function $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}g_n(x)$ of which each $g_n$ is known to be $C^1$.

I'm looking for sufficient conditions for $f$ to be $C^1$ as well. Also, I'd appreciate an example where each $g_n$ is $C^1$ but $f$ (well-defined) is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's a theorem that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of differentiable functions that converge pointwise to a function $f(x)$ and the sequence $(f_n')$ converge uniformly to a function $g(x)$ then $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=g(x)$.

Applying the theorem to your case, a sufficient condition would be the uniform convergence of the series $(\sum_{k=0}^n g_k'(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

To see this note that the sequence of partial sums $s_n(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n g_k(x)$ converge pointwise to $f(x)$. Moreover since each $g_{k}$ is $C^1$ then the sequence of partial sums $s_n(x)$ is differentiable (being a finite sum of differentiable functions) and if the series $s_n'(x)$ converges uniformly to a function $h(x)$ then by the above theorem $f'(x)=h(x)$. Moreover since each $g_k$ is $C^1$ then the sequence of partial sums $s_n'(x)$ is continuous (being a finite sum of continuous functions) and since it converges uniformly to $f'(x)$ then $f'(x)$ is continuous by the uniform limit theorem.

Lastly, for your example - take the fourier series of the heaviside step function. Each $g_k$, being a multiple of a cosine function is in fact $C^{\infty}$ while the function to which the series converges is not even continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any results if the sequence $g_n$ does not converge to a function? Still each $g_n$ is $C^1$

Comment: Is it not enough to conclude $f$ is $C^1$ if $f$ itself converges uniformly and not the series of derivatives? Thanks to each $g_n$ being $C^1$

Comment: 1. Regarding your first question - the sequence $g_n$ regardless of its regularity has to converge to zero since the tail of any convergent series is zero.

Comment: 2. Regarding your second question - no you can have a uniformly convergent sequence which converges to a function which is not $C^1$. Again, Fourier series can be illustrative here. Take the Fourier series of $f(x)=|x|$. This will be $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-(-1)^n}{\pi^2 n^2}cos(n \pi x)$. Here each $g_n$ is infinitely differentiable and the series converges uniformly but the function to which it converges $f(x)=|x|$ is not $C^1$.

Comment: So anyway the series of derivatives must uniformly converge. 
Is it true that if the series of derivatives converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test then the original series also converges uniformly? And this cannot be obtained with other tests? More precisely if the series of derivatives is uniformly convergent thanks to Cauchy’s test for example, then we cannot say anything about the uniform convergence of the original one?

Comment: You're right, if the series of derivatives converge uniformly then the original series converge uniformly as well.